# To Deploy Microservice with Helm and Kustomize together

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kustomize

I am trying to deploy one microservice with the combination of helm chart and Kustomize. I have tested with both of them .How can I use both of them together. Any example of the directory structure can give please

Comment: There's plenty articles that you can find using your search engine about this topic. Unless you have a specific question, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: See also [Kustomize documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/chart.md)

Comment: Thank you Gael .the link given by you is very helpful.If you get any more link related it then it's a great helpful for me.I am new in this field and not able to find any good document

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [HelmChartInflationGenerator](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/builtins/#_helmchartinflationgenerator_).
I use a manifest like this in ArgoCD:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

helmGlobals:
  chartHome: *local path to charts*

helmCharts:
- name: *chart name*
  version: v1.0.0
  valuesFile: values.yaml
  additionalValuesFiles:
  - values-file-1.yml
```